# Tic Tac Toe Simple Code against Computer - Issue in Main

Tags: java, arrays, methods, static-methods

I am finishing up a fairly simple tic tac toe Java coding program, with a method for the computer moving getting called to the main, and when the program runs it won't switch from playerX to playerO.

```
static void computerMoves() {
    int besti = 0;
    int bestj = 0;

    generateScore();
    scoreBoard();


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            if (scoreBoard[i][j] > scoreBoard[besti][bestj]); {
                besti = i;
                bestj = j;
            }
        }
    currentBoard[besti][bestj] = playerO;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int userMove;
    char player;

    initializeBoard();
    player = playerX;
    do {
    printBoard();
    if (player == playerX) {
    userMove = askUserForMove();
    makeMove(userMove, player);}
    else {
        computerMoves();
    }
    if (player == playerX)
        player = playerO;
    else 
        player = playerX;
    } while (isGameOver() == false);

    System.out.println("Game Over");
    printBoard();
```

The result should be a full game of tic tac toe. Right now I am just getting 'Please enter number between...' which is the askUserForMove method.

Comment: Where do you initialize `char playerX` and `char playerO`?

Comment: At the beginning. static final char